# How to check if something is serializable with cereal

Tags: c++, cereal

I need trait to check if serialization is possible using cereal. I've already used

```cpp
cereal::traits::is_output_serializable<T, cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>
cereal::traits::detail::count_output_serializers<T, cereal::BinaryOutputArchive>
```

(plus the symmetric version for input serialization).

Putting such checks in `if constexpr` passes (evaluates to true even though my type is not serializable) but later on it breaks within cereal saying that the very same trait failed(!) I'm using `T=cv::Mat`.

- Is there an alternative check available?
- Any idea why such a thing may fail? Is my archive type wrong?

Comment: could you, maybe, post some of the code for the `if constexpr` that passes and then fails?

Comment: My own test with concepts gave me the same result. Interesting.

Comment: @Timo Well, both concepts and `std::is_invocable` will check if the expression is well formed. Unfortunately, since these functions are templates in cereal, they are indeed type-wise always invocable. What happens is that during compilation a static assertion is triggered, and that's when things fail. So Maybe checking with those methods stops earlier than the actual compilation

Comment: @LorahAttkins yeah I was just digging through cereal and found the asserts as well. They're not concept friendly it looks like. However the trait from cereal itself works for me with a custom type in a static assert. Can you post how you use the trait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own based on some static asserts I found in Cereal. I have a base case with a bunch of specialisations I need for my own code. The specialisations are needed as the base case is true for `std::shared_ptr<T>` even if T isn't itself serialisable.

```
    /// Meta programming constant, can you serialise the type T to the Cereal archive ARCHIVE?
    template<typename ARCHIVE, typename T>
    static constexpr bool kHasCerealOutputArchiver
      = not std::is_pointer<T>::value and cereal::traits::detail::count_output_serializers<T, ARCHIVE>::value != 0;

    // specialisation for vectors
    template<typename ARCHIVE, typename T, typename A>
    static constexpr bool kHasCerealOutputArchiver<ARCHIVE, std::vector<T, A>> = kHasCerealOutputArchiver<ARCHIVE, T>;

    // specialisation for shared_ptrs
    template<typename ARCHIVE, typename T>
    static constexpr bool kHasCerealOutputArchiver<ARCHIVE, std::shared_ptr<T>> = kHasCerealOutputArchiver<ARCHIVE, T>;

    // specialisation for shared_ptrs to const
    template<typename ARCHIVE, typename T>
    static constexpr bool kHasCerealOutputArchiver<ARCHIVE, std::shared_ptr<const T>> = kHasCerealOutputArchiver<ARCHIVE, T>;


    /// Meta programming constant, can you serialise the type T from the Cereal archive ARCHIVE?
    template<typename ARCHIVE, typename T>
    static constexpr bool kHasCerealInputArchiver
      = not std::is_pointer<T>::value and cereal::traits::detail::count_input_serializers<T, ARCHIVE>::value != 0;

    // specialisation for vectors
    template<typename ARCHIVE, typename T, typename A>
    static constexpr bool kHasCerealInputArchiver<ARCHIVE, std::vector<T, A>> = kHasCerealInputArchiver<ARCHIVE, T>;

    // specialisation for shared_ptrs
    template<typename ARCHIVE, typename T>
    static constexpr bool kHasCerealInputArchiver<ARCHIVE, std::shared_ptr<T>> = kHasCerealInputArchiver<ARCHIVE, T>;

    // specialisation for shared_ptrs to const
    template<typename ARCHIVE, typename T>
    static constexpr bool kHasCerealInputArchiver<ARCHIVE, std::shared_ptr<const T>> = kHasCerealInputArchiver<ARCHIVE, T>;
```